# Unreal Engine установка в линукс. Нету репоситории на github'е

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Репозиторий Unreal Engine 4 нету на Guthub'e. Уже нельзя чтоле установить UE4 в Linux ?

Comment: Unreal Engine 4 не является проектом с открытым исходным кодом, соответственно его нельзя найти в публичных репозиториях.

Comment: Да спасибо. Заметил.

Comment: По другому никак да установить ?

Comment: Его можно получить по лицензии у вендора. Т.е. зарегистрироваться у них на сайте и т.д.

Comment: Понятно спасибо.